# How is 'instanceof' implemented in the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, instanceof

Does it use reflectione, and if so, what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: BTW, try  to avoid `instanceof` and typecast constructs, mostly because of performance

Answer (score 14):

Jon is right about how the operator maps to byte-code.  As far as implementations, most JVMs represent objects in memory as [tagged unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) of the loaded concrete classes:

> a tagged union, also called a variant, variant record, discriminated union, disjoint union, or sum type, is a data structure used to hold a value that could take on several different, but fixed types.

So `x instanceof MyClassType` can be answered by looking at a [sparse boolean matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) that has a bit set when a concrete type is an instance of a class type.

`x instanceof InterfaceType` is a bit trickier but similar methods can help with that too.

The JVM can keep a large sparse matrix in memory with a row per nominal types (class or interface types) and a column per class type.

For example:

```
                           [all nominal types]
                     Object String Integer Number Comparable Iterable ...
[only       String   ✓      ✓                     ✓
 concrete   Integer  ✓             ✓       ✓      ✓
 types]     ...
```

When the JVM has to garbage collect classes, maintaining this matrix becomes trickier, so you usually store a row with the class object.

---

[Proxy classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) are an interesting corner case but my best guess is that proxy class definition involves generating some byte-code at runtime that then goes through the normal class loading system in most JVMs.

Answer (score 12):

It's part of the JVM instruction set, basically - there's a specific `instanceof` instruction. So for example, a method like this:

```
public static void checkString(Object x) {
    if (x instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

is compiled into:

```
public static void checkString(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: instanceof    #2                  // class java/lang/String
     4: ifeq          15
     7: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    10: ldc           #4                  // String Foo
    12: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    15: return
}
```

(That's just the output of `javap`.)

The [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/) has details of what the instruction has to do. See [section 6.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof) for exact details of the instruction. How it's implemented is up to the VM implementation - but one sample implementation could be:

- Check whether the first operand is `null` (and return `false` if so)
- Find the execution-time type of the object that the first operand refers to.
- Navigate up the type hierarchy (including implemented interfaces) until you can prove that the actual type either is or is not compatible with the second operand.